# How to change dashboard icon in react-admin?

Tags: react-admin

it easy to change an icon of a resource by providing a prop. How to change the icon of dashboard without defining the whole custom navigation?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, interesting question.

To make sure you can reproduce this, let's go through the steps:

- Within your `<Admin/>`, you pass this prop;

```js
// "CustomLayout" is your custom layout component
<Admin {...props} layout={CustomLayout} />
```

- Within your `CustomLayout`, you pass this prop;

```js
import { Layout } from 'react-admin';

// "CustomMenuLayout" is your custom menu component
<Layout {...props} menu={CustomMenu} />
```

- Within your `CustomMenu`, define the menu link for the root path to be rendered **first**;

```js
import { MenuItemLink } from 'react-admin';
// import any icon as usual
import DashboardIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Dashboard'; 

export const CustomMenu = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <MenuItemLink
         to="/"
         primaryText="Dashboard"
         leftIcon={<DashboardIcon />} // pass the icon here
         exact
         {...props}
       />
       {/* other menu links follow... */}
    </div>
  );
};
```

It sure looks like a lot of work to "just change a dashboard icon" but you have two advantages:

1. You start to gain more control of how your app will appear thus more customization.
2. You start to understand `react-admin` from the underneath thus it becomes faster for you to debug issues.

Answer (score 1):

The key is `<DashboardMenuItem leftIcon={...} />`

Here is the detail:

1. Use custom layout

```js
<Admin layout={MyLayout} ... />
```

2. in MyLayout, use custom Menu

```js
import { Layout } from 'react-admin';
import MyMenu from './MyMenu'

const MyLayout = props => <Layout
    {...props}
    menu={MyMenu}
/>
export default MyLayout
```

3. Last thing, content of MyMenu

```js
import {
    DashboardMenuItem,
    MenuItemLink,
    getResources,
} from 'react-admin'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import {
    Storefront,
    ViewList,
} from '@material-ui/icons';

const MyMenu = () => {
    const resources = useSelector(getResources)
    return (
    <div>
        <DashboardMenuItem leftIcon={<Storefront />} />
        {resources.map(resource => (
            <MenuItemLink
            key={resource.name}
            to={`/${resource.name}`}
            primaryText={
                (resource.options && resource.options.label) ||
                resource.name
            }
            leftIcon={
                resource.icon ? <resource.icon /> : <ViewList />
            }
            />
        ))}
    </div>
    )
}

export default MyMenu
```